# Image noise filtering on line chart image

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

What kind of other methods are there available in Python `CV2` package to remove the noise in this image in order to keep the line as smooth as possible?

I have already applied `Medianfiltering` and `Gaussianfiltering` on this picture. I have tried the function `findContours` but this highlights the noise as well. Applying antoher `Medianfiltering` on this image is then 'breaking' the line.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check out [image denoising](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_photo/py_non_local_means/py_non_local_means.html#image-denoising-in-opencv) in opencv.

Comment: Thanks, after that I have applied GaussianBlur and now the noise is gone :-)